# react google maps onMarkerClick event not trigger in mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
                         initialCenter={{
                             lat: lat,
                             lng: lng
                         }}
                         onClick={this.onMapClicked}
                         zoom={zoom}>

                        {this.state.marker.map((data, index) => {

                                return (


                                    <Marker
                                        ref={this.onMarkerMounted}
                                        key={index}

                                        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}

                                        name={data.name}
                                        phone={data.phone}
                                        icon={{
                                            url: data.icon,
                                            anchor: new this.props.google.maps.Point(20, 20),
                                            scaledSize: new this.props.google.maps.Size(80, 80)
                                        }}
                                        position={{"lat": data.lat, "lng": data.lng}}/>

                                )
                            }
                        )}
                        <InfoWindow
                            marker={this.state.activeMarker}
                            visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
                            onClose={this.onClose}
                        >
                            <View style={{width: 100, height: 20}}>
                                <Text style={{
                                    fontWeight: '600',
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: "#54AD58"
                                }}>{this.state.selectedPlace.phone}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </InfoWindow>
                    </Map>
```

In React google maps, the Marker Touch event not working in mobile view. Same function works well on Desktop View. But when i call this function for mobileview it does not works properly.

If i changed the function called this.onMarkerClick() this should call the fuction when i touch the map but this will not working properly. onMapclicked event working in mobile view and desktop view. i don't know what's the problem..

Comment: Have you tried the google maps demo on your mobile before? I worked with this a long time ago and back then the touch event was not supported for mobile. Click, long clicks etc. did not trigger on mobile. Could just be that it is still not supported.

Comment: any other solution to solve this problem.

Comment: window.addeventlistener is the solution?